# Calculate Div Position on Browserwindow resize

Tags: jquery, animation

when I run my web page, an animation is running and positioned the navigation to a specific position. if I make the browser smaller, the position is no longer correct. only when I reloaded. you can make live this somehow?

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
var newSize = viewportHeight - footerHeight + 30;
var $navigation = $('#navigation');
var $logo = $('#logo');
var $win = $(window).scroll(function () {

    $navigation.animate({
        top: newSize
    }, 1500, function () {
        // $('#navigation .active').removeClass('active');
        // $('#navigation .current').addClass('active');
        $('#arrow').css('display', 'block');
        console.log('animation 1 finished');
    });
    )};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a function:

```
function animatediv(){
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
var newSize = viewportHeight - footerHeight + 30;
var $navigation = $('#navigation');
var $logo = $('#logo');
$(window).scroll(function () {

    $navigation.animate({
        top: newSize
    }, 1500, function () {
        // $('#navigation .active').removeClass('active');
        // $('#navigation .current').addClass('active');
        $('#arrow').css('display', 'block');
        console.log('animation 1 finished');
    });
    )};
}
```

And then simply call it on resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 animatediv();
});
```

Keep in mind you will also have to call it on document.ready so it does the animation when you run the page.

```
$(function(){
 animatediv();
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work.
http://www.lignoconcept.com/n/
i think the var $win = $(window).scroll(function ()  is the problem

Comment: @herrsaidy oups didn't notice it, why are you using it, check out the edit